# tensorflow.merge_all_summaries() hangs

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've been having a problem where if  I run `sess.run(tf.merge_all_summaries())` during training, the program will hang. This was also brought up in [a github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3704), although I'm not sure that my problem is the same.

For reference, this is the code I'm using to train:

```
logits = fcn8.upscore  # last layer of the network
loss = softmax_loss(logits, lb, pipe.NUM_CLASSES)

train_op = build_graph(loss, global_step)
saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.all_variables())
summary_op = tf.merge_all_summaries()

sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)
summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(FLAGS.train_dir, sess.graph)

for step in range(FLAGS.max_epochs * pipe.EPOCH_LENGTH):
  if sess.run(queue.size()) == 0:
    sess.run(enqueue_files)

  _, loss_val = sess.run([train_op, loss])

  if step % 10 == 0:
    print('loss at step {}: {}'.format(step, loss_val))
    summary = sess.run(summary_op)  # hangs here
    summary_writer.add_summary(summary, step)
```

Is this a common thing? Or is there some error I've made in writing the training code? Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT:** It seems like the only time this happens is when the queue is empty when I try to merge summaries. I wonder if this is a coincidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `summary_op` likely triggers a Queue dequeue which will hang when the queue is empty.

One work-around is to restructure your code using variables so that summaries don't trigger queue dequeue, like here --
[TensorFlow: Reading images in queue without shuffling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36783560/tensorflow-reading-images-in-queue-without-shuffling/36783901#36783901)

A simpler work-around is to initialize your Session with a deadline so that your empty dequeues fail with `DeadlineExceeded` after some time rather than hanging

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
queue = tf.FIFOQueue(capacity=5, dtypes=[tf.int32])
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.operation_timeout_in_ms=2000
sess = tf.InteractiveSession("", config=config)
try:
    sess.run(queue.dequeue())
except tf.errors.DeadlineExceededError:
    print "DeadlineExceededError detected"
```